# Why doesn't infinite-loading-vue3 work in a Laravel Project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am having a problem using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/infinite-loading-vue3) in a Vue file. The project is being done with InertiaJS and Laravel.

The controller is composed of the following code:

```php
public function getSaldosContables()
{
    $saldocontables = SaldoContable::paginate(10);

    return response()->json($saldocontables);
}
```

And the Vue file contains the following code:

```html
<template>
  <app-layout>
    <template #header>
      <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">Listado</h2>
    </template>

    <div class="py-12">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
          <div id="app" @scroll.passive="scrollear">
            <infinite-scroll
              @infinite-scroll="loadDataFromServer"
              :message="message"
              :noResult="noResult"
            >
              <div>
                <div
                  v-for="repo in saldocontables"
                  :key="repo.idsaldocont"
                  style="margin-bottom: 20px"
                >
                  <div>
                    <img :src="repo.idsaldocont" alt="" style="height: 50px" />
                  </div>
                  <div>{{ repo.nombresaldocont }}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </infinite-scroll>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-layout>
</template>


<script>
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/AppLayout";
import InfiniteScroll from "infinite-loading-vue3";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  components: {
    AppLayout,
    InfiniteScroll,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      saldocontables: [],
      page: 1,
      noResult: false,
      message: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async loadDataFromServer() {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get("/obtenerSaldos?page=" + this.page);
        if (result.data.data.length) {
          console.log(this.page);
          this.saldocontables.push(...result.data.data);
          this.page++;
        } else {
          this.noResult = true;
          this.message = "No result found";
        }
      } catch (err) {
        this.noResult = true;
        this.message = "Error loading data";
      }
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.loadDataFromServer();
  },
};
</script>
```

The Laravel route file handles the following encoding:

```php
Route::get('/obtenerSaldos', [SaldoContableController::class, 'getSaldosContables']);
```

The data loaded in the database is rendered correctly. The problem is generated when the Infinite Scroll must load the following pages with the respective data. When it reaches the end of the page, it remains only loaded with the data of Page 1 and does not update the data contained in the following pages taking into account the pagination returned by the Backend.
This can be seen in the following image:

[image: image 1]

If I delete the following lines from my Vue:

```html
<app-layout>
    <template #header>
      <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">Listado</h2>
    </template>
</app-layout>
```

The Template responds correctly and the Infinite Scroll also works perfectly.
You can see it in the following image:

[image: image 2]

The problem is that by doing this in the view the components that refer to the Side Menu, Top Menu, Responsive Menu, etc. do not appear.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: You do not seem to be using inertia.js in any capacity, judging from the code you posted. This seems more to be an issue with [Vue Teleport](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/teleport.html#teleport).